# *bcdboot* error code [c000003a]

Tags: windows-7, efi, bcdboot

An attempt to restore Windows 7 EFI boot record with `bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s f:` failed with

`BFSVC: Failed to create a new system store. Status = [c000003a]`

Does anyone have a clue what this error code stands for (search did not help)?

For those interested boot failed completely after the restart which followed trying to change the paging file to another drive (an SSD one).

1. I tried changing EFI partition type to another random one with "set id=..." described in [superuser.com/questions/725322](https://superuser.com/questions/725322/issue-with-a-windows-7-boot-issue-involving-the-bcd-perhaps)
2. tried all bootrec commands listed in [superuser.com/questions/891804](https://superuser.com/questions/891804/bootmgr-is-missing-how-to-replace-windows-7-embedded-boot-files-after-applying)
3. tried various bcdedit commands described in other posts.

What else can I do to get it booting again?

Comment: must add that solutions mentioning **[c000003a]** were tried without any success.

Comment: What solutions? Be specific please.

Comment: 1) tried changing EFI partition type to another random one with "set id=..." described in _http://superuser.com/questions/725322/issue-with-a-windows-7-boot-issue-involving-the-bcd-perhaps_
2) tried all _bootrec_ commands listed in http://superuser.com/questions/891804/bootmgr-is-missing-how-to-replace-windows-7-embedded-boot-files-after-applying
3) tried various _bcdedit_ commands described in other posts...

Comment: c000003a = STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND - {Path Not Found}
The path %hs does not exist.

Comment: @magicandre1981 great! and what does %hs stand for?

Comment: this is a placeholder for the actual string/missing folder

Answer (score -1):

A few years ago, I was having a problem like yours and it turned out that an anti-virus program had disabled automount. The fix for my system was:
Open a command prompt with administrator privileges. Or in your case, from Win RE.

type "diskpart" (without the quotes) and press enter.

when the 'diskpart' prompt appears, type:
"automount enable" (again without the quotes) and press enter.

"exit"

I don't remember if a reboot was needed, but it wouldn't hurt

Good Luck, I hope this helps.

Comment: great, and I wish I could say this has helped me! 

Opted for a clean (re)install - I though 4 hours of drinking coffee and waiting for the updates to finish is the time spent better than acquiring the knowledge of the recent boot technology with no long term value - and without a guaranteed solution within the given time limit!